# Will "stereo mix" work with an amplifier?

Tags: audio, speakers, microphone, stereo

I have realtek sound card, and trying to record sound with `Java sound API`.
My PC's speakers are connected with an amp. and my mic is connected with amp.

Now, if I play an audio file, and sing through mic, will these both will be recorded?As they both have output to my speaker.
Or only the audio from PC?
I cannot test it as I don't have set up right now.
Windows 7, 32-bit.
Stereo Mix-default device.
Thank you.

Comment: `my mic is connected with amp` Do you mean that the microphone is boosted before going to the PC, or that it's connected to the same amp as the speakers (but not direct to the PC)?  In order to record stereo mix and mic at the same time, you will have to have recording software capable of getting both sources at the same time.  (I'm sure they exist, but every one I've played with only did one source at a time.)

Comment: @techturtle `or that it's connected to the same amp as the speakers (but not direct to the PC)? ` yes same amp. but not direct to the PC.I am recording through Java, line by line.But also its -"what you hear" so will it record both?

Comment: Stereo mix only records what the PC is generating.  In order to add in audio from a mic, you have to have the mic routing back into the PC, which it does not sound like you are doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will not work. 'Stereo mix' is a virtual recording device that uses the output of your sound card as its signal, so any audio playing on your computer can be captured from that recording device. Although this feature is often used to record 'what I'm hearing', it requires that what you're hearing originated from your sound card. In this setup, a different source is used. In fact, the signal from your microphone never reaches your computer, so it can't possibly be recorded there.

However, since you already have the audio file, there is no need to record it again. Instead, you can connect the mic directly to your pc and capture your voice while playing the song over headphones, then merge both tracks using audio editing software.